# Keep a value in SQL from a PHP script ? (UPDATE statement)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

I've got a PHP function which receives some parameters. Each parameter corresponds to a VALUE of one SQL line.
What I would like to do, is to update the values according to the parameters ; but with having some parameters not mandatory. So if a parameter is set to 'keep', the VALUE has to keep its current value. This is where I'm stuck.

Here is the function :

```php
function upt($id, $p1, $p2)
{
    if ($p1 === 'keep')
        $p1 = 'columnName1';
    if ($p2 === 'keep')
        $p2 = 'columnName2';
    $REQ = $DB->prepare('UPDATE ms_cart_products SET columnName1=:P1, columnName2=:P2 WHERE ID=:ID');
    $REQ->execute(array(
        ':P1' => $p1,
        ':P2' => $p2,
        ':ID' => $id));
    $REQ->closeCursor();
}
```

Obviously, this does not work (even if I had the secret hope that making $p1 = 'columnName1' would work as if I made COL1=COL1 directly in the SQL console).
The VALUE is literally set to 'columnName'.

Any ideas ?


Thank you,
Florian

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what database do you use.

Comment: Hi,

sorry for the long delay of response, but I was unfortunately away for a moment.
Otherwise, your SQL trick is fully functional and really helped me a lot !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you use either PostgreSQL or MySQL (I don't mention other RDBMSes here, please tell us if you use something else).  Then you can write an `UPDATE` like

```
...
SET columnName1 = COALESCE(NULLIF(:your_value, 'keep'), columnName1)
...
```

`NULLIF` returns its first value when the too values provided are different, otherwise it returns `NULL`.  `COALESCE` then returns the first non-NULL value.  This way, if you pass 'keep' to this expression, the inner `NULLIF` part evaluates to NULL, therefore the `COALESCE` returns the value kept in `columnName1`.  Otherwise the `NULLIF` returns the passed value and `COALESCE` evaluates to that.

See the docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

or

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create a class but this works too.

```
# Outside the function 
$col1;
$col2;

function upt($id, $p1, $p2)
{
    # Inside the function
    global $col1;
    global $col2;
    if ($p1 === 'keep')
    {
        $col1 = 'columnName1';
    }
    if ($p2 === 'keep')
    {
        $col2 = 'columnName2';
    }
    $REQ = $DB->prepare('UPDATE ms_cart_products SET columnName1=:P1, columnName2=:P2 WHERE ID=:ID');
    $REQ->execute(array(
        ':P1' => $col1,
        ':P2' => $col2,
        ':ID' => $id));
    $REQ->closeCursor();
}
```

Comment: Hmm I don't understand, I think we misunderstood ourselves.
$p1 can be set to either a new value to set, either 'keep' which means do not update the value. Same for $p2.
This function would be helpful for me because I often need to update one value and not the other.